# Serial Communication in OpenCV

Tags: c++, c, opencv, serial-port, arduino

I am building an application involving identification of color of object and then sorting it with the help of a robotic hand manipulator. The code for Color Identification is ready in OpenCV, what I do not know is how to transfer this data to my Arduino UNO board connected by USB. I have made this kind of application previously in MATLAB, but have no idea how to do it in OpenCV. Do we have any way to send data over Serial port in OpenCV?

Comment: I don't know how to do it in C/C++ but it is super easy with python if you are familiar with it.Use opencv python bindings to port your C/C++ code to python.Combine it with python serial communication library and you are good to go.

Comment: I have never worked on python, but I wanted to work on it for a long time now, may be now is the time. Thanks @tez . Can you suggest some good web sites for the same.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using [OpenFrameworks](http://www.openframeworks.cc/documentation/)?  I personally haven't played around with OpenCV but I have played around with serial communications to arduinos on OF.  OF also includes the OpenCV library so you can link your work with it.

Comment: OF seems like a valid option, but I am in some trouble, have to submit this project tomorrow, not much time left, and it will take some time to get adapted to OF environment.

Comment: I'm sure there's libraries out there that can handle serial communications.  OF is the only one I can think of off the top of my head.  Good luck!  I would love to see the result!

Answer (score 0):

**Prerequisites** :Install opencv with python bindings.I usually work on Mac Os.Its pretty easy installing opencv with python bindings on mac using macports.I have no idea about windows and linux but there is no shortage of tutorials to do so.Just google.

And about python,don't worry,You can learn a lot of python in 2 days.[Google python classes](http://code.google.com/edu/languages/google-python-class/) are definitely a good start.

Check [this](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html?highlight=imread#imread) out for different python opencv methods.And [this](http://opencvpython.blogspot.in/) is a good site for starting opencv with python